# Inequality with square roots conditions

Tags: inequality, contest-math, substitution, sum-of-squares-method

Let $a,b,c>0$ and $a+b+c=9$.
Prove that: $$(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c})^2\geq ab+bc+ca.$$
(Edit) I'm sorry. The problem should have beeen:
Let $a,b,c\geq1$ and $a+b+c=9$.
Prove that: $$(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c})^2\geq ab+bc+ca.$$

Since $(a+b+c)2\geq3(ab+bc+ca)$ or $ab+bc+ca\leq27$, all we need to do now is to prove $\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{ca}\geq9$, which I cannot.

Comment: Your thoughts ?

Comment: This inequality seems to be popular today. Some online contest due soon?

Comment: Since $(a+b+c)^2\geq3(ab+bc+ca)$ or $ab+bc+ca\leq 27$, all we need to do now is to prove$\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{ca}\geq9$, which I cannot.

Comment: because $\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{ca}\geq9$ it is not necessarily true as if you take $a,b$ near $0$, $c$ near $9$ LHS is near zero

Comment: I think my method cannot solve this problem because I can prove that $\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{ca}\leq a+b+c=9$.

Comment: @Conrad This problem from old Bulgarian contest. I think have found a nice solution by SOS for this one.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a=2x+1$, $b=2y+1$ and $c=2z+1$.

Thus, $x$, $y$ and $z$ are non-negatives, $x+y+z=3$ and we need to prove that:
$$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{2x+1}\geq\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}(2x+1)(2y+1)}$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(2x+1+2\sqrt{(2x+1)(2y+1)}\right)\geq\sum_{cyc}(4xy+4x+1)$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(4x-4xy)\geq\sum_{cyc}\left(2x+1-2\sqrt{(2x+1)(2y+1)}+2y+1\right)$$ or
$$4\sum_{cyc}(x^2+2xy-3xy)\geq3\sum_{cyc}\left(\sqrt{2x+1}-\sqrt{2y+1}\right)^2$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(x-y)^2\left(1-\frac{6}{\left(\sqrt{2x+1}+\sqrt{2y+1}\right)^2}\right)\geq0.$$
Now, let $x\geq y\geq z$.

Thus, $$y^2\sum_{cyc}(x-y)^2\left(1-\frac{6}{\left(\sqrt{2x+1}+\sqrt{2y+1}\right)^2}\right)=$$
$$=y^2\sum_{cyc}(x-y)^2\left(1-\frac{6}{2x+2y+2+2\sqrt{(2x+1)(2y+1)}}\right)\geq$$
$$\geq y^2\sum_{cyc}(x-y)^2\left(1-\frac{3}{x+y+2}\right)=y^2\sum_{cyc}\frac{(x-y)^2(x+y-1)}{x+y+2}=$$
$$=y^2\sum_{cyc}\frac{(x-y)^2(3x+3y-x-y-z)}{3x+3y+2(x+y+z)}\geq y^2\sum_{cyc}\frac{(x-y)^2(x+y-z)}{5x+5y+2z}\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{y^2(x-z)^2(x+z-y)}{5x+5z+2y}+\frac{y^2(y-z)^2(y+z-x)}{5y+5z+2x}\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{x^2(y-z)^2(x-y)}{5x+5z+2y}+\frac{y^2(y-z)^2(y-x)}{5y+5z+2x}=$$
$$=\frac{(x-y)^2(y-z)^2(2x^2+2y^2+7xy+5xz+5yz)}{(5x+5z+2y)(5y+5z+2x)}\geq0$$ and we are done!